# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CustomersController#create (attr_accessible is set)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mass-assignment

In my controller, I've got error when create action and try create model [can't mass-assignment], but
in my spec, my test of mass-assignment model its pass!?!

My Model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :doc, :doc_rg, :name, :birthday, :name_sec, :address, :state_id, :city_id, :district_id,
                  :customer_pj, :is_customer, :segment_id, :activity_id, :person_type, :person_id

  belongs_to    :person , :polymorphic => true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :histories
  has_many :emails

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      conditions = []
      conditions << ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]
      find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end 
end
```

I`ve tired set attr_accessible in controller too, in my randomized way.

the Controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
  attr_accessible :doc, :doc_rg, :name, :birthday, :name_sec, :address, :state_id, :city_id, :district_id, :customer_pj, :is_customer

  autocomplete :business_segment, :name, :full => true
  autocomplete :business_activity, :name, :full => true

  [...]

end
```

The test, my passed test

```
  describe "accessible attributes" do
  it "should allow access to basics fields" do
    expect do
      @customer.save
    end.should_not raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
  end    
end
```

The error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CustomersController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: doc, doc_rg, name_sec, address, state_id, city_id, district_id, customer_pj, is_customer
```

https://github.com/megabga/crm

1.9.2p320

Rails 3.2

MacOS

pg

Comment: Can you show the source code of your #create controller method? You also don't need attr_accessible in the controller, so you should remove that. Your test is testing save, but I imagine you're calling update_attributes in the controller. It helps to have a minimal failing example, and you're on the right track with trying to write a test to replicate the behavior.

Comment: ok! my bad, in my controller set an oldest class, then old class don`t have a this attributes. Thanks, its help me wherever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my bad, in my controller its setting an oldest class. Then old class don`t have attributes passing in parameters. Sorry!